# Is it possible to upload an iOS app to App Store for internal testing from Xcode 7 beta?

Tags: xcode, testflight

Is it possible to upload an app archive to the App Store in Xcode 7 beta for internal testing with Test Flight?

Has anyone been able to do that?

Note: I am asking about submission for **prerelease internal testing with Test Flight**. I am well aware that releasing the app to the public is not possible from beta versions of Xcode.

#### Update

I was able to use Xcode 7 beta and upload binary to the App Store's  prerelease section. After that I was able to open it from the Test Flight. Code Signing identity was: iOS Developer. Provisioning profile was "Automatic". Both values were set for Debug and Release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to upload your application via beta Xcode 7. But, the problem is to have potential bugs and that's also why they name it beta. You should take this as a risk when you decide to upload your application via new Xcode. It's okay to go with this way if you are handling your personal application. For your client or business, it's the best to use a stable version.