# Unable to "Upload to App Store" Xcode 7 beta 4, watchOS 2

Tags: watchkit, provisioning-profile, testflight, watchos-2, xcode7-beta4

I have to upload my app on the App Store in order to do some internal testing with Test Flight. Even if I am still using beta version, this is possible according to this question [Is it possible to upload an iOS app to App Store for internal testing from Xcode 7 beta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602756/is-it-possible-to-upload-an-ios-app-to-app-store-for-internal-testing-from-xcode)

Unfortunately I am not able to do it.
First some details, my app name is Workout and I have created an application for both iOS 9 and watchOS 2. In the photo you can see the largest of my project (automatically created by Xcode).

[image]

I have tried a lot of configurations, here are some
a) (there are six settings, like the six icons in the image)

```
Workout (the blue icon)-> Code Signing Identity: automatic, Provisioning Profile: App Store Distribution
Workout (the light blue monochromatic icon)-> Code Signing Identity: iPhone Developer, Provisioning Profile: App Store Distribution
WorkoutTests-> Code Signing Identity: iOS Developer, Provisioning Profile: Automatic
WorkoutUITests-> The same as above
Workout WatchKit App-> Code Signing Identity: iPhone Developer, Provisioning Profile: App Store Distribution WatchKit
Workout WatchKit Extension-> Code Signing Identity: iPhone Developer, Provisioning Profile: App Store Distribution WatchKitExtension
```

b) The same Provisioning Profiles but everything on iPhone Developer except for WorkoutTests and WorkoutUITest where, since I have chosen automatic Provisioning Profile, I only had the option iOS Distribution and not iPhone Distribution
c) Similar to b) but I have set App Store Distribution provisioning profile for WorkoutTests and WorkoutUITests
d) I followed this guide http://basememara.com/submitting-apple-watch-apps-to-the-app-store/ and I have set the options like it is suggested, except for Workout WatchKit App where if I didn't chose any Provisioning Profile, Xcode gave me a compile error, so I put one.

I think all Certificates and App ID are ok, I think I am only messing up with Code Sign in. Every time I create the archive and press Upload to App Store after some work it appears this error.

[image]

I have also created a new iOS+watchOS project afraid of having accidentally changed some important settings, but nothing. I have also tried to create an Ad Hoc Distribution provisioning profile, nothing. I have also tried to upload the WatchKitApp version (while the above mentioned guide told to upload the iOS version), nothing. It is always been displaying the same error.

I do not know what to do, please help.

Additional information, I created the certificates, the App ID et cetera following the above mentioned guide http://basememara.com/submitting-apple-watch-apps-to-the-app-store/ so if you ask how have I done something (for instance what target I have compiled), in that (short) guide there are all the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saw the same problem recently and was solved by removing ~/Library/Developer using:

> rm -rf ~/Library/Developer

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In the last week of September I will continue to work at the project so I will try your suggestion.